# Bad Data exception during RSA decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I was working on a project. Encryption is working fine but when it comes to decryption my program is throwing "Bad data Exception". How do I remedy this problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        byte[] cipher;
        byte[] plain;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private static string Encrypt(byte[] plain)
        {
            byte[] encrypted;
          RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

                StreamReader StRe = new StreamReader("D:\\PjesaVetemPublike.xml");
                string VetemPublikeXML = StRe.ReadToEnd();
                rsa.FromXmlString(VetemPublikeXML);
                StRe.Close();
                encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(plain, true);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted);
        }

        private static string Decrypt(byte[] encrypted)
        {
            byte[] decrypted;
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

                StreamReader StRe = new         
         StreamReader("D:\\PjesaPublikeDhePrivate.xml");
                string PublikeDhePrivate = StRe.ReadToEnd();
                rsa.FromXmlString(PublikeDhePrivate);
                StRe.Close();

                decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(encrypted, false);   //THE ERROR APPEARS RIGHT HERE

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            plain = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtPlain.Text);
            txtCipher.Text = Encrypt(plain);

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            txtDekriptuar.Text = Decrypt(cipher);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is likely an indication of a bad key. Check your keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among other problems you are assuming that the ciphertext can be converted to UTF-8 meaningfully, and that isn't guaranteed.

If you want to encrypt text and transmit/store the encrypted contents as text you need to follow this pattern:

Encrypt(textIn => textOut):

- Convert textIn to bytesIn via some encoding.  UTF-8 is pretty good.
- Encrypt bytesIn to bytesOut.
- Apply a lossless encoding to bytesOut.  Base64 is almost always the best choice for this, and is the best one that's built in to .NET.  (`textOut = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesOut)`).
- Return textOut.

Decrypt(textIn => textOut):

- Apply the inverse transform from Encrypt to turn textIn to bytesIn.  So likely `Convert.FromBase64String`.
- Decrypt bytesIn to bytesOut.
- Apply a text encoding transform to turn bytesOut to textOut. There's nothing that really says that this needs to be the same as the one used in Encrypt, but it probably makes sense to do so.

The problem with using UTF-8 (or ASCII or UCS-2, etc) for a textual representation of encrypted data is that the encrypted data can legitimately contain a byte whose value is `0x00` (or a control code, linebreak, etc).  While .NET, for the most part, happily transports embedded null characters in a string it definitely can be a large source of confusion (and not all languages/functions handle it the same).

Other fun characters:

- What does your language/function do for an embedded `0x7F` (Delete)?
- If you store the string in a single-line text field, what happens to any CR or LF characters?  What does your program do on Windows if it gets CR without LF, or LF without CR?
- A Unix command-line with `0x13` (^S) may appear to hang, but it's just waiting on `0x11` (^Q).

What encodings to use for storing ciphertext?  Well, anything that safely packs control characters.

- Base64: 33% increase in storage: 3 bytes => 4 ASCII characters == 4 bytes
- Hexadecimal (aka Base16): 100% increase in storage, but easier to inspect than Base64
- Other, less common options are summarized at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding#Encoding_standards.

Comment: Excellent Step by Step universal solution! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your key pair is correct, the issue is that you're using different [padding schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Public_key_cryptography) for encryption and decryption.

The second argument that is passed to `RSACryptoServiceProvider#Encrypt` and `RSACryptoServiceProvider#Decrypt` denotes whether OAEP is used. During encryption you're requesting OAEP, but during decryption you're requesting PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. Those are not compatible. Just use OAEP which is more secure.

You should use

```
decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(encrypted, true);
```

Comment: It's saying An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 128 bytes.

Comment: It seems that your private key is not compatible with your public key. Additionally, RSA cannot be used to encrypt arbitrary data (you would need to implement [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)).